# Rendering Hard shading?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a material that does not make any sort of soft shading at all -- rather it averages together and spreads it all over the face.

[Here's an image of buildings from Darwinia where the buildings all have flat faces for shading, no softness. Just solid.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cvstDsq6bBU/maxresdefault.jpg)

Is there a way to average it out like that, besides just using emission and manually assigning materials of different colors manually?

Comment: What render engine are you interested in?

Comment: Cycles render..